# Normalizing inputs decreases accuracy

Tags: python, neural-network, normalization

I am training a neural network for audio classification.

I implemented normalization of the inputs as it is suggested in any book/course about neural networks. I normalized them to have 0 mean and unit variance. 
The problem is that I did not get better accuracy, neither in the training nor in the test set. On the contrary, both accuracies reduced considerably (4-8%)

I implemented it as follows:

```
mean = np.mean(X_train, axis = 0)
std = np.std(X_train, axis = 0)

X_train = (X_train-mean)/std
X_test = (X_test-mean)/std   # apply the same transformation to the test set
X_val = (X_val-mean)/std     # apply the same transformation to the validation set
```

Where X_train is a matrix of dimensions (4000,60,130,1) where (batch, height, width, #channels)

Did I do something wrong with the code or my problem might be somewhere else?
Is normalization of the inputs always supossed to improve accuracy and/or time of convergence of the optimization algorithm?

Comment: According to an answer I just read on Quora, it might happen if your input features have vastly different scales, so that one feature will dwarf the other. It seems to be happening here with batch(?). Just taking a guess here.

Comment: I thought normalizing was actually done to avoid having vastly different scales. But anyhow it is not the case here.